# JSF2 CDI action called twice in case of exception

Tags: exception, jsf-2, cdi

In our Java EE 6 application we're calling an action of a CDI Bean to search for a person. Inside this action there is a call to a webservice.

If the services throws an exception (not catched in CDI Bean action) the action is executed a second time. (If there is no exception the action is executed only one time).

Suddenly after the second action call, which throws the same exception, or ExceptionHandler gets called.

Why is the action called twice inside the invoke application phase and how can we get rid of the second call?

Comment: Might help to get a backtrace of the 2nd invocation

Comment: Where is the code? You're probably placing the ws call in the wrong place, a getter maybe.

Comment: The webservice call is in the CDI controller action invoked by a commandButton. This action is invoked twice, why? Can't find any clue in JSF lifecycle